# What is meant by "All Polynomials of the form $p(t) = a + t^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have a math homework problem that goes like this:

Determine if the given set is a subspace of  $\mathbb{P}_n$ for the appropriate value of $n$:

All polynomials of the form $p(t) = a + t^2$, where $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}$

I don't really understand what the problem means by "All polynomials of the form ...". Does that mean that if I could multiply $t^2$ and $a$ by any constants and get a "polynomial of the form"?

Comment: $\mathbb P_n$ and $\mathbb R_n$ do not appear to be standard notation. Do you know what they mean in this context?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_n$ represents the set of all polynomials of degree $n$, I believe. And $\mathbb{R}_n$ should have been $\mathbb{R}$. Sorry about that.

Comment: Some of the polynomials that qualify as being of the right form are $2+t^2$, $\frac{3}{4}+t^2$, $\pi+t^2$.  Polynomials that don't qualify are for example $1+t+t^2$, $5+2t^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing the sentence wrong.  It does not refer to a
$$
\text{polynomial of the form}.
$$
It refers to a
$$
\text{polynomial of the }{\Big(}\text{form }p(t) = a+t^2{\Big)}.
$$
I.e. a polynomial that has that particular form.  The particular form is that it's a constant plus $t^2$.

Comment: so the set of polynomials that satisfy this are are basically just the set of any $\mathbb{R}$ number plugged in for $a$, added to $t^2$?

Comment: Yes. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: OK, Sorry for asking such an elementary question.